# Storing bit flags and BCD lookup data in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a CLI that interacts with an external USB device. The device's status is discovered by reading the Status registers, 24x 8 bits wide. The register values are read from a serial port and arrive as an array of Strings:

```rb
=> ["000", "000", "000", "000", "086", "003", "000", "000", "255", "255", ...]
```

The registers are in 2 formats, bit flags and BCD (I'm not sure of Correct terminology here). They can be mix also.

###### Bit flags

| Bit 7 | Bit 6 | Bit 5 | Bit 4 | Bit 3 | Bit 2 | Bit 1 | Bit 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error 10 | Error 11 | Error 12 | Error 13 | Error 14 | Error 15 | Error 16 | Error 17 |

A value of 34 (0b00100010) means 'Error 16' and 'Error 12' are present.

###### BCD

| Bit 2 | Bit 1 | Bit 0 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | State A |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | State B |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | State C |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | State D |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | State E |

A value of 3 (0b00000011) means 'State D'

Is there an elegant Ruby way (or conventions) for storing and looking up this type of String data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't quite understand what's the relation between the 24*8 Status registers and Bit flags and BCD, but I think it's just about the number base conversion.
You can use `to_s` if you want to change the number base from 2 to 36.

```rb
5.to_s(2)
# => '101'
255.to_s(2)
# => '11111111'
36.to_s(36)
# => '10'
```

After you convert the number to binary, you can use rjust to supplement with the leading zeros.

```rb
5.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')
# => '00000101'
```

Then you can use the index of the string to decide what is the status now.

For Bit flags, you can make a array of errors:

```rb
errors = ['Error 10', 'Error 11', 'Error 12', 'Error 13', 'Error 14', 'Error 15', 'Error 16', 'Error 17']
'034'.to_i.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0').chars.each_with_index.map do |bit, index|
  bit == '1' ? errors[index] : nil
end.compact
# => ["Error 12", "Error 16"]
```

For BCD you can make a Hash variable for the states:

```rb
states = {
  '000' => 'A',
  '001' => 'B',
  '010' => 'C',
  '011' => 'D',
  '111' => 'E',
}
bits = '003'.to_i.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')[-3..-1]
states[bits]
# => 'D'
```

btw, your markdown tables don't display well...

Comment: Thanks Kevin, sorry for confusion, the Status Register contains 24 bytes (Registers). Each 8 bit register is formatted as above.

Comment: Some of the registers contain bit flags and BCD data, but I can work with your solution and store register specific layout data also.

Comment: @kiwi if it answers your question, you could accept the answer thereby he could gain the points.